# нужно сделать телеграмм бота с поиском по бд sqlite то есть человек пишет телеграмм боту к примеру имя Алексей и бот выдает все совпадения из бд

Tags: python, sqlite3, aiogram

```
import logging
from sqlite3 import Cursor

from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('data.db')
cur = conn.cursor()

# Объект бота
bot = Bot(token="токен")
# Диспетчер для бота
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
# Включаем логирование, чтобы не пропустить важные сообщения
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


# Хэндлер на команду /test1
@dp.message_handler(commands="start")
async def cmd_test1(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply("Добро пожаловать!")

#поиск
@dp.message_handler(commands=['profile'])
async def get_profile(msg: types.Message):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
    cur = conn.cursor()

def read_sqlite_table(developer_id):
    try:
        sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('data.sqlite')
        cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
        print("Подключен к SQLite")

        sqlite_select_query = """SELECT * from ANSB where ?"""
        cursor.execute(sqlite_select_query, (developer_id, ))
        print("Чтение одной строки \n")
       record = cursor.fetchall()
       print("дата:", record[0])
    print("Быстрый поиск и Название(пишется кратко название организации):", record[1])
    print("Фамилия:", record[2])
    print("Имя:", record[3])
    print("Отчество:", record[4])

    cursor.close()

    except sqlite3.Error as error:
        print("Ошибка при работе с SQLite", error)

read_sqlite_table(3)


executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=True)
```

Comment: код рабочий но ничего кроме /start не работает

Comment: а что еще должно работать? судя по этому коду - ничего